# What stereotypes are true when it comes to religion, genders, race, military, and the government?

Tags: military, demographics, religion, gender

Provide accurate information of evidence along with the stereotype that is true base on one or more of the subjects that I listed above.

Comment: Sounds like some assignment. We do not accept assignments here, only questions. And if this is your school assignment, it would be honest to work on it by yourself. If any question during your work arises, community is ready to help.

Answer (score 2):

There are none.  That is because if it is true it is not a stereotype.

"A widely held but simplified or incorrect opinion or idea about a person or thing."

Comment: Could you cite the source for the definition that you give?

Comment: It's just from the dictionary (via google)

Answer (score 2):

[*Stereotypes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype) are widespread generalizations, which can be both true or wrong.

> In social psychology, a stereotype is a generalized belief about a particular category of people. It is an expectation that people might have about every person of a particular group. The type of expectation can vary; it can be, for example, an expectation about the group's personality, preferences, appearance or ability. Stereotypes are sometimes overgeneralized, inaccurate, and resistant to new information, but can sometimes be accurate.

The issues with stereotypes is that they are not grounded in actual experience or knowledge, but result from hasty generalizations, from hearsay or simply because many people think so (it even might be that people think so that at some time in the past the belief was true.)

**Example: Russian mindset**
*Russian mindset* is occasionally cited in this community as an explanation for some actions by the Russian government: that is the Russian are supposedly suspicious of everyone's intentions, uncooperative, cynical, treating any interaction as a zero-sum gain (if one party wins, the other necessarily loses), etc.

One could argue that many Russians indeed behave in such a way, and this has explanation in their culture and history - e.g., every Russian above 40 has lived through the collapse of the USSR, when people were virtually told that everything that they believed and hoped for was wrong, and the truth is just the opposite. They also had to live through the phase of "wild capitalism" in the 90s, where many people were plunged into poverty, while the most unscrupulous became millionaires. It is natural then that they are suspicious of government, hold opinions like "All the politicians are crooks", and do not trust anyone.

One the other hand, this stereotype clearly does not apply to all the Russians. Firstly, because younger Russians have never lived this experience. Also because *Russian* is a vague designation - it may apply to the Russian citizens, to ethnic Russians, to Russian speakers (20% of whom live outside of modern Russian territory) or even to anyone from what was formerly known as the USSR. Finally, Russians are inherently no different from other people's, and one can expect that a Russian who were born and grew up in the US would be no different from an American whose parents came on the Mayflower (which is actually the case with Russian immigrants who came in the end of XIXth and beginning of XXth centuries - they merged seamlessly, often less attached to their origins than Italians, Chinese or Irish - all Russian neighborhoods, like Brighton Beach, is a relatively recent phenomenon, compared to Little Italy or Chinatown.)

Comment: "because younger Russians have never lived this experience" except for right now?

Comment: @kandi *the experience of everything that they were taught to believe being turned upside down*? No, they have never lived through it - regardless of what they think about the current situation.

Comment: as one of "younger Russians", I can assure you that the path from being probably the most globalized and pro-Western generation in entire Russian history to realizing that the West is an enemy feels pretty much like being turned upside down

Comment: @kandi I doubt that any young Russian has changed their opinion on whether the West is an enemy or not. On the other hand, probably no one believe that the USSR enjoyed the high level of life, that it was bringing peace and freedom to other nations, that Eastern Europe met with flowers Russian tanks, and other stuff that was everyday in the Soviet time (pretty similar to the everyday image one see in the US or Europe, but with a caveat that one can check the info against the foreign sources, if one wishes and knows languages.)

Comment: @kandi "the West is an enemy".  Oh, that is pretty self-serving given that your [*state-controlled* mainstream TV](https://www.euronews.com/next/2022/05/04/what-is-russia-s-poseidon-nuclear-drone-and-could-it-wipe-out-the-uk-in-a-radioactive-tsun) broadcasts [nuke-da-UK fantasies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SnTkc0r6gk).  And keeps his job.  Tell us more about how it is all the West's fault, we love to hear it.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I think what they mean is how representation of the west might have changed in the Russian media. IMHO, some of the inflammatory anti-Russian rhetoric in this SE shouldn't be reassuring.

Comment: @RogerVadim Looking at the word "realizing" right before my quoted text, yours seems like a very generous interpretation.  Yes, there is a lot of Russophobia rampant and, strangely enough for me, I believe one of the saddest outcomes of this stupid war is how Russian expats, regardless of their politics, risk being demonized for decades to come.  I would never *start* talking about the war to a Russian I'd meet on the street here for example.  Like Germans after WW2, but also not without reason:  this war, why and how it is being waged reflects badly on them.